# GL/gl.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

Usually I use Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. Today, I have to use freeglut. All the files are installed correctly, but I don't have file `GL/gl.h`.
I have installed the Windows Platform SDK. I tried it in Visual Studio 2017 and Clion, but every time I have this error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/gl.h': No such file or directory.
```

I also tried to add `#include <windows.h>` before the `#include <GL/glut.h>` and checked for updates for Windows and video driver.

The code I tried to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 1);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Where is gl.h installed on your system?  Is your search path setup properly?

Comment: I can't find this file using search in C:. How can I get it? It isn't included in freeglut-MSVC or glut.

Comment: No clue, I don't use Windows.  Try your favorite search engine.

Comment: I have founded this file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um\gl

Comment: I remember having that problem with OpenGL1 a long time ago (not sure about freeglut); various implementations called the directories different things. If you want OpenGL2+, I'd recommend http://glew.sourceforge.net/, which takes care of that.

Comment: @vchkhr2: gl.h is part of the windows sdk (you already found it on your harddrive). This path should be in the default include directories of your project. Check if in the include directories `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)` is present (it should be inherited from project default.